# Deployment Strategy for Require JS Optimized/Concatenated Website Files

Tags: javascript, git, optimization, requirejs, web-deployment

My question is partly technical and partly about deployment strategies and workflow. I built a project using Require JS. It includes a number of distinct js modules, and is built upon Kirby CMS. The directory structure of the project is something like this:

```
project    
  assets    
    styles
      style.css
    js   
      scripts   
        script1.js
        script2.js
        script3.js  
      vendor   
      app.js
    images    
    fonts    
  content
  ... 
  kirby folders
  ....
```

The file app.js is called in the footer of my site's page like so:

```
<script data-main="/assets/js/app" src="/assets/js/vendor/require.js"></script>
```

It configures RequireJS by calling the `requirejs.config()` function and then calls the main script file that loads everything else using RequireJS's `requirejs()` function.

I've used [RequireJS' s optimization tool](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) to compile the project in such a way that the optimized files are all dumpted into a directory called dist (a name I just picked up from [this tutorial](http://www.webdeveasy.com/optimize-requirejs-projects/)). So in the end dist contains a replication of every directory and file under assets, only optimized, and the file app.js is a concatenated and optimized version of all the js modules that I have in the project. So far so good.

What I am unsure about, however, is how I'm the supposed to make use of this new secondary version of all the code. What for instance if  I want to deploy a version of the site to the production server without all the source js files? Each time I deploy the site, I would need to go through my code and in every place that I referred to files under the `assets` directory, I would need to replace that with `dist`. I deploy using git and [beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/). One way to do this would be to manage different branches for staging, production, and development, in which the production and perhaps staging branches have references to the files under dist, but this seems awkward.

So my question is given this kind of optimization set up, which if you look at the tutorial linked above is one way to do this, how then do you manage the switch to the optmized version of everything seemlessly, without having to  go back into your code and change everything up? Is there some key part of the process that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each time I deploy the site, I would need to go through my code and in every place that I referred to files under the `assets` directory, I would need to replace that with `dist`.

I've looked at the tutorial you've linked to and do not see how it is true for the tutorial. The tutorial does not use absolute paths, so should be deployable from `dist` just as well as from the directory that contains the pre-optimization sources. If you cannot do this for your application, that's because you've done something different from the tutorial. Your `script` tag, for instance, shows absolute paths.

So the solution is to design your application to avoid absolute paths. This way, you won't have to change paths when you deploy from `dist`. I'm using this very method to deploy optimized and non-optimized versions of one of my apps.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you've done that in your project, or the basic concept. It'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The tutorial you linked to contains everything. Look at how the `script` tag in `index.html` HTML avoids absolute paths for `data-main` and `src`. Look at how the `require.config` call in `main.js` and how the `build.js` shown in the tutorial's explanation avoid absolute paths. This illustrates everything that needs illustrating to handle the problem you've described in your question. My app is much bigger than this tutorial, and has peculiarities that are irrelevant to your problem and would just serve to throw you off. And the basic concept is this: don't use absolute paths.

Comment: This part of that tutorial makes very little sense to me. He's using relative paths, but the script tag is located in `index.html`. So the relative path is if I am not mistaken relative to the location of that file which is in his server root. The directory `js` is a subdirectory of the root. In fact, when I downloaded the optimized version of that project  it didn't load the optimized and concatenated version. I suppose, *even with relative paths*, the index.html script tag would need to refer to the file within the `dist` subfolder of root for that to happen. But that's the scenario to avoid

Comment: The way you describe it, I think you are looking at the wrong `index.html` file. In [the optimized version](http://www.webdeveasy.com/code/optimize-requirejs-projects/todo-mvc-optimized.zip) the `index.html` file is at `todo-mvc-optimized/dist/index.html`.

Comment: Oh now I see what the tutorial is doing. It replicates the entire project and the the contents of dist is what is deployed! Interesting. I'm trying to think about how this kind of process could be worked into my deployment workflow, which normally uses beanstalk and git. Still not sure how that could work. Anyway, thank you for your patience and explanation.

Comment: I'm seeing 2 questions in your question: a RequireJS question, and the rest, which is largely independent from the RequireJS issue. The RequireJS issue is what I addressed in my answer because from my perspective there's no telling whether taking care of the RequireJS issue would have *by the same token* taken care of the issue you have using git and beanstalk. I use git and make for my app but once the principle of "don't use absolute paths" is taken care of the rest falls into place, or is a matter of personal choice, or is dictated by the specifics of my project.

Comment: What you answered has help me separate the one question from the other. I've posted a new question to address that second question about deployment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606202/directory-structure-and-conventions-for-development-and-production-versions-of-w)