# Directory Structure and Conventions for Development and Production versions of website

Tags: git, requirejs, web-deployment

I have a project that I maintain with [git](http://git-scm.com/) and deploy using [beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com). I also have built its javascript components using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) and I am optimizing its code at the end using RequireJS's optimization tool. I use that tool to replicate the files of the site and only with all the code minmized and concatenated in a new directory. However, I am unsure how best to place this directory and manage its deployment via git and beanstalk. My git repository currently maintains three branches: `develop`, `master`, and `production`. I deploy production to the live production server. Here is what I am thinking. I would keep the three branches but modify the repo to have a base directory that includes two directories, the main project and its optimized and minimized version as siblings, like so:

```
project
  raw-version-of-site
  minimized-version-of-site
```

I would then setup beanstalk -- and I am fairly sure this is possible -- to deploy only the `minimized-version-of-site` folder to the production server.

My question is 1) is this a good way to go about this? and 2) what naming conventions should I use for the two subdirectories. I thought of `trunk` and `dist`, but I am not sure if these conventions have other meanings and I would be confusing things. Secondly, I am a bit worried that by using `trunk` for example I would be confusing the fact that there is an underlying structure of branches.  Thoughts?

Comment: I would avoid versioning your minified version of the site. That should be generated by a build process from the "raw version". I'm not sure if Beanstalk can do that for you.

Comment: Hmmm. The thing is that I only want to deploy the minified version without the source code.

Comment: Yes, that is very common. Tasks like minifying JavaScript, generating CSS from LESS or SASS, etc. need to run, then you deploy the output of that build phase to your server. But anything that can be generated from other files isn't really source code, is it? Treat source files like source files and anything generated as a build artefact.

Comment: Just making sure I understand your meaning. The reason not to check in the generated code to the repo is that it is, in the way you indicated, not source code? I follow if so, but the hitch is that if I do not check it into the repo, I cannot deploy with beanstalk, which of course uses git...

Comment: That's what I would recommend, although I didn't realize that Beanstalk *requires* Git for deployment. It [lists FTP, SFTP and SSH](http://beanstalkapp.com/features/deployments) as deployment targets, none of which have any dependency on Git. Targets like Heroku have their own build phase that can build artefacts for you, so that might be another option (push "raw" site and let your deployment target's build phase generate the minified version).

Comment: You can deploy with those tools, but the source is always a git repo...  Interesting about Heroku.

Comment: You may be able to roll your own minification step on the server as a [post-deploy shell hook](http://support.beanstalkapp.com/customer/portal/articles/75806-how-do-i-trigger-hooks-before-and-after-a-deployment-). If you can install RequireJS on the server you should be good to go. The pre- and post-deploy web hooks likely won't be helpful as they are inherently web-based.